# Fork - How to ensure parent runs first?

Tags: c, signals, fork, race-condition

So I'm writing a Unix shell in C, and have been encountering a race condition.  I've determined that I can resolve it if, after one of my Fork() calls, I can ensure the parent runs before the child.  Is there any way that I can do that using signaling or any other type of inter-process communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a signal handler and let the child wait for it, e.g. SIGUSR1.

Comment: Would I be able to do that within the function where I made the Fork() call, or would I have to set up another signal handling function?

Comment: if(fork == 0) is the child and from that moment on you can do what you need in the new process. Usually you do some cleanup first, though. Udsing a pipe might be better, though, because then you can defnitely wait on the parent until it sends some command.

Comment: I did some playing around with pipes and it seems to be working great.  Thanks!

Comment: A pipe is very effective, not least because all the parent has to do is close it to release the child (whose `read()` call returns with zero bytes to read — EOF).